# I'm trying to upload and display images that the user selected in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, image, upload, display

I'm trying to upload and display images that the user selected by using the `id` element in HTML; e.g.

HTML:

```html
<span id="propicout"><img src="#" alt="PROFILE" id="propicout"></span>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```js
const propic = document.getElementById("propicin").value;
```

Now I just need to set the id, "propicout" to the image the user uploaded.

#### I tried some YouTube tutorials, some were complicated, and some didn't work. I also looked at stack-overflow but they didn't really match what I was doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you're looking for is [`URL.createObjectURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL).

This creates a temporary URL pointed to the image data in-memory (or cached on disk) that you can use like any other URL.  You assign that to the `src` attribute on your image element, and you're good to go.

```
document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  document.querySelector('img').src = URL.createObjectURL(e.currentTarget.files[0])
});
```

JSFiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/qg1j8e25/1/

*(Also, by the way... you're re-using an ID in your HTML.  Don't do that.  IDs should only be used once.)*